Is there a way to test whether an external contract implements (or does not implement) a given interface method?
How would you determine whether a given contract implements a particular interface method without reverting?
interface IRandomMethod {
    function getUint() external view returns (uint);
    function isNotImplemented() external view returns (address);
}

// let's assume this contract once deployed, will be address(0xTEsT)
contract AddressToBeQueried { 
    function getUint() public pure returns (uint) { return 0; }
}

contract MethodSniffer {
    IRandomMethod methodtest = IRandomMethod(address(0xTEsT));
    // how to query methodtest.isNotImplemented() without reverting?
    // the following doesn't seem to work as success is always true
    // (bool success,) = address(methodTest).call(abi.encodeWithSignature("isNotImplemented()"));
}

You can technically query it by using call and encodeWithSignature but success always seems to return true which isn't helpful. Ideally I would want a Boolean that returns false on a nonexistent method, or a catchable Error event so that I can implement code logic depending on whether an arbitrary contract implements a given method.

It does return true when the function is implemented and false when it's not. How come it's always returning true for you? I'm testing using ^0.8.24. What version are you using?

0.8.25 EVM cancun. From testing call it seems that when the address is address(0) the boolean always returns true. Also, do you know why using a try catch in the constructor reverts the deployment transaction?

One way is to use try-catch error handling. Here's a minimal code for the same:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

interface IRandomMethod {
    function getUint() external view returns (uint256);

    function isNotImplemented() external view returns (address);
}

contract AddressToBeQueried {
    function getUint() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return 0;
    }
}

contract MethodSniffer {
    IRandomMethod methodTest;

    constructor(address contractAddress) {
        methodTest = IRandomMethod(address(contractAddress));
    }

    function testIsNotImplemented() external view returns (bool) {
        try methodTest.isNotImplemented() returns (address) {
            // Method exists
            return true;
        } catch {
            // Method doesn't exist
            return false;
        }
    }

    function testIsImplemented() external view returns (bool) {
        try methodTest.getUint() returns (uint256) {
            // Method exists
            return true;
        } catch {
            // Method doesn't exist
            return false;
        }
    }
}


0.8.25 EVM cancun. From testing call it seems that when the address is address(0) or any generated address like address(uint160(12091)), the boolean always returns true. Not sure why that is. Also, do you know why using a try catch in the constructor reverts the deployment transaction?

Note that I am using Remix. I just discovered that for "deployed" addresses in the VM, try catch and the rest work just fine, even in the constructor. But for "undeployed" addresses generated like address(uint160(2)), things revert.  I'm not sure if there's a way to keep the VM implementation from reverting in the latter case. It seems like it would also revert in the mainnet, if you try to call an address that doesn't technically exist.

It’s possibly due to the fact that it’s unable to instantiate the Interface using the undeployed/dummy addresses.

For future readers use the check if (address(methodTest).code.length > 0) before try catch to prevent reverts on arbitrary addresses.

I created a new question on Safemoon reflection code optimization if you're interested; you seem talented, so you'd likely have the ability to solve it

This is one of the reasons ERC165 exists. A smart-contract that is compliant with this interface will implement function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceID) external view returns (bool).
